# Does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" /> disables conditionals?

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-statements, compatibility

We must add conditionals for loading different js and css to fix the compatibility issues.

But I hate when the compatibility mode unfixes some things, so I read that adding this line disables that mode and so far in a site I tested worked like a charm:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

So, I read also that this disables the use of conditional tags like:

```
 <!--[if lt IE 7]>
```

Is it true?

Comment: well I guess...but...sometimes IE still does whatever it wants and wont load things so...dunno...anyone having experience may help

Comment: Please be more mindful with your tags.  "fix" is for FIX protocol, not for when you need to fix something.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer 10+ disables Conditional Comments, so if the user has IE10, then yes, the conditional comments will be ignored if you set this declaration in your markup.

Comment: If you use Enterprise Mode conditionals should work, as well as other legacy functionality that is no longer supported.

Comment: @ChrisLove refers to the new "Enterprise Mode" feature introduced in IE11, which behaves as a new sort of "Compatibility Mode." It requires an IT Administrator explicitly put your site in a list to run in IE8 emulation mode.

Comment: Actually, individuals can use enterprise mode. It would be in the tools menu. If on a system with group policies any site an end user designates for enterprise mode would report back to the administrators so they can add it to group policy.

Comment: @ChrisLove Individuals can use enterprise mode only if that feature is enabled by IT. And as this conversation has nothing to do with the question at hand, I'm not sure these comments are suitable.